# Recovering Celery From a Database Outage

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have Celeryd/RabbitMQ running on a Fedora box, communicating with a MySQL
database on a separate box. I've noticed that, on rare occasions, if
there's even the slightest problem connecting to the MySQL database
(even for a few seconds), celeryd will crash with the error:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
'mydatabasedomain' (111)")
```

and fail to reconnect even when the database becomes available again.

Currently, I'm forced to manually restart the celeryd service to get
celery running again. Is there a more graceful and automatic way to
recover from these types of event? Is there any feature of celeryd to
just quietly wait, logging the OperationalError, and reconnect instead
of exiting out entirely?

Comment: What's using MySQL? Is it that you're using the SQLAlchemy broker, connecting to the MySQL DB?

Comment: Long ago when I was writing celery tasks I was managing sql connections myself on the task level. So at the beginning of the task I was setting up connection and at the end of the task I was releasing it, with appropriate exception handling when interfacing with the database so if anything happened to the database the task was returned to the queue. This was not the cleanest solution but worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to fix this by simply using a config flag, but you could consider running your worker using supervisor (s. http://supervisord.org).

This is even mentioned in the celery docs (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#supervisord) including a link to some example config files.

Comment: Same issue here. Celery doesn't provide a solution? A external daemon is the only known option? In my case I have two boxes running a Python app+Celery+RabbitMQ, connecting to the same Google Cloud SQL database using SQLAlchemy. Eventually I get in one of the machines a SQL OperationalError `(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`. Despite handling the exception, Celery worker processes are shut down in both machines, without Celery logging. Only RabbitMQ logs the connections closing abruptly

Comment: I think this is a different issue though (although both should be handled by a more robust celery). The error message you quoted is known to happen if a db connection is open for too long (you might be able to fix it by increasing the timeout in your mysql config)